# Hard drive partition not responding

Tags: windows-7, window

Hi i went through your blogs regarding the IT support, I have  Samsung laptop and for last one week it is given me problem, my laptop hard drive has 2 partition by the name of C and D, whatever iam doing on C drive like to open my computer or documents it is taking too long and the main reason to message you is that it is showing a D drive partition in 'MY COMPUTER' but it is not opening,  and all my data is saved in D drive,  I even tried to installed new windows 7 but still is same,  I tried to use option of disk defragmenter but it's say 'invalid parameters'  I tried to used bitlocker option but same message I got invalid parameters, I don't want to lose my data, iam confused that if the problem is with hard drive then why C drive partition is working and D is not, when I right click on D drive for properties it Is taking too long screen shot I will send you soon,  I will highly appreciate you if you can help me I don't want to lose my data thanks

Comment: Bad hard drive. The question though is what to do about it. You should state the name of a hard drive, maybe it's a known to be rubbish one. You could try connecting it to USB and see if you can get data off it. Maybe make an image and somehow do data recovery on that if possible. or directly run some data recovery programs, look into that

Answer (score 0):

Those are the signs of a failing HDD. The best thing you can do is to recover your important data as fast as possible, because your windows partition will fail soon and you will not be able to boot anymore after a while. I know this from my experience, as i had a failing drive too (the same signs). Try not to use it at all as it will short it's lifespan with every move.

Try the [following recovery programs](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/filerecovery/tp/free-file-recovery-programs.htm) (or copy it manually) to get yor most important data out of your laptop to any external HDD or a few USB flashdrives to match the size of your data.